# Password seems not to protect a pfx file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, security, deployment, assembly-signing

I created a new pfx file for signing assemblies, using Visual Studio's (2010) automated "new" option. I then copied it to another project - and it doesn't prompt me for a password. I checked, and the assembly *is* signed.

So it seems that anyone who has the file can sign assemblies with it. Or is there a way to secure it?

Comment: Properly saved PFX is definitely encrypted and protected. So either your PFX was not saved with the password applied, or your signing is performed using the certificate in Windows Certificate Storage and not the certificate in file.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp The password was applied - since trying to export it (by clicking on it) asks for a password, ans accepts only the correct one. As for Visual Studio using the Certificate Store to sign - perhaps somehow that's what's happening, but there is no option like that at all when signing assemblies. (Only for signing the clickonce manifest.) So how would that happen?

Comment: How do you "export" the PFX? PFX is external and can be imported (and then you are asked for a password) - is that what you meant? Also, are you Authenticode-signing or strongnaming assemblies?